# I need help in <ul> tags

Tags: html, css

I am looking to add this point mark- '*' in HTML. I need to add this to my

  tag to get this to work but I don't know how.

I need it sonething like this:

Text1

Text2

Text3

Instead of points, I need the stars.

And so on and so forth. Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with some simple CSS.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: "* ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something a little bit better, this will actually centre your bullets too - as opposed to them being towards the top of the list item.

```css
ul li {
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:15px;
}
ul li::before {
  content:'*';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```